# Auto shutdown server if there was no activity

Tags: 12.04, server, scripts, shutdown, cron

My server should shutdown after 01:00 am, if there was no activity in the past hour.
Lets say there was the last connection at 00:43 then it should check again at 01:43.

How to write such a script/how to get last login time?
Based on ssh connection

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will provide a list of users and idle times, one user per line.

```
w | tr -s " " | cut -d " " -f 1,5 | tail -n +3
```

Important: See the NOTES section in the man page for *w*. The line above produces something like this:

```
username1 0.00s
username2 48.08s
```

Then use *cron* to execute the script that you created to utilize the output from *w*.
Use whichever scripting language you prefer. Perhaps you do not care about usernames, only idle times?

```
w | tr -s " " | cut -d " " -f 5 | tail -n +3
```

Any result < 3600 seconds does not meet the one-hour idle time requirement.

> My server should shutdown after 01:00 am, if there was no activity in the past hour. Lets say there was the last connection at 00:43 then it should check again at 01:43.

Doesn't that require a dynamic modification of the cron job itself? I think I might be satisfied to run it once hourly; otherwise, I would have to run the script every minute to acquire that precision.

Here is a script in PHP that works well on Linux Mint 13. It should be fine for Ubuntu or any other Linux.

```
#!/usr/bin/env php
<?php
/* Shutdown Script
 *
 * If idle times exceed a defined value or if no users are logged in,
 * shutdown the computer. If running from cron there should be no "dot"
 * in the script file name. Make the script executable.
 *
 * Caveat: running the script as root in an interactive shell will cause
 * immediate shutdown, as though typing 'shutdown -P now'.
 * (It should only be run from cron.)
 */
$max_idle_time = 3600; // seconds
$cmd_idle_time = 'w|tr -s " "|cut -d " " -f 5|tail -n +3'; // idle times
$shutdown_now = true; // boolean

function shutdown() {
    exec('/sbin/shutdown -P now'); // or -h
}

// Form an array from the output of $cmd_idle_time
$idle_times = explode("\n", shell_exec($cmd_idle_time));

foreach ($idle_times as $idle_time) {
    // Are there no users logged on, or did root run this from a shell?
    if (empty($idle_time)) {
        continue;
    }

    // Remove trailing "s" from idle time and round to nearest second
    $idle_time = round(substr($idle_time, 0 , -2));

    // Cancel shutdown if any user's idle time is less than $max_idle_time
    if ($idle_time < $max_idle_time) {
        $shutdown_now = false;
    }
}

// If the $shutdown_now boolean is still true, shutdown.
if ($shutdown_now === true) {
    shutdown();
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Well a linux server will almost never beet the requirements to shutdown that you have stated. Linux connects to it's self constantly. That said, You could probably rig something up.

/var/log/messages will show new ssh connections.

`ps aux | grep ssh` will show active ssh processes

Together you could write some kind of script to check /var/log/messages for connections in the last hour, make sure there are no active connections, and then shutdown.

[This article](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/os-automatic-shutdown/index.html) from ibm might help.